# Pick and RDF/SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, u2, multivalue-database, pick

Anyone have any interest in intergrating RDF and/or SPARQL with a PICK database?
Has anyone tried this yet?
I have some thoughts about what to try. One idea is to figure out how to create a file with a dictionary that defines some correlatives that allow data to be pulled from the file as RDF, as one or many of n-triple, turtle, n3 or XML. Another idea is a PICK BASIC SPARQL endpoint.

Unfortunately, I no longer work in a place where a PICK database is available for testing.
I suppose I could set up a Maverick instance, but I'd rather do this on D3 or U2.

Comment: It's more like undead. The medium-sized companies that bought into it years ago just can't truly model their data any other way, or can't afford to hire someone smart enough to untangle the multivalues into relational tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having had a quick skim read of the Wikipedia article on PICK the basic ideas of hash file based data management seem similar to some of the stuff used in various existing disk based Triple stores such as 4store (http://4store.org).  I could be completely misreading this and be wrong of course!

You can always try your question on SemanticOverflow as well - http://www.semanticoverflow.com

Comment: Did so, moved the thread to http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/357/pick-rdf-anyone

Answer (score 2):

You can download a free Universe or Unidata personal edition from the Rocket Software website.  These are similar to Pick and even have a Pick option when creating a new account (at least Universe does).

[Rocket Software](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/downloads/)

Comment: And I have an *awesome* tutorial on setting it up on modern linux here http://serverfault.com/questions/103975/how-do-i-install-u2-universe-on-ubuntu-or-debian